# Mapping dispatch props and connecting them not working properly

Tags: typescript, react-redux, dispatch, react-props

I have the following class:

```
type globalProbs = {createActivity:(period:Models.Period)=>void}
type props = { period: Models.Period, curriculum: Models.Curriculum };

type allProps = globalProbs & props;
export class PeriodEditCell extends React.Component<allProps, {}> {
```

which I export using connect like so:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<globalProbs>): globalProbs => {
    return ({
        createActivity: Firebase.actionCreators.createActivity
    })
  }

export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(PeriodEditCell);
```

and in the action creators in firebase I have this:

```
export const actionCreators = {
     createActivity: (period: Models.Period): AppThunkAction<any> => async (dispatch, getState) =>{
//....
      }
}
```

My AppThunkAction interface:

```
export interface AppThunkAction<TAction> {
  (dispatch: (action: TAction) => void, getState: () => RootState): void;
}
```

My issue is that when I call this.props.createActivity(blah) in the PeriodEditCell component the function seems to get to createActivity but doesn't go into the body, so something is going wrong at AppThunkAction

Not sure what I'm doing wrong as I've done similar things in the past and it has worked...

Comment: looks like you'll have to debug it

Comment: react-redux's `connect()` expects `mapStateToProps` as the first argument, could it be that?